# Use Schroder-Berstein Theorem to prove $\left[ 3, 4 \right]$ and $\left( 5, 7 \right]$ are bijectable

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Use the Schroder-Bernstein Theorem to prove that $ | [3,4] | = | (5,7] | $.

I have no idea where to even begin. I know I need to think of a function that the interval from $3$ to $4$ is less than or equal to $(5,7]$ and greater than or equal to $(5,7]$. I am struggling to even understand the theorem properly and don't know how to state my function.

Comment: 1) Find an injective map $f:[3,4]→(5,7]$ 
2) Find an injective map $g:(5,7]→[3,4]$

Comment: You need to product injective functions, one from $\left[ 3, 4 \right]$ to $\left( 5, 7 \right]$, and the other from $\left( 5, 7 \right]$ to $\left[ 3, 4 \right]$. The Schroder-Berstein Theorem will then quarantee that the two sets are bijective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint :**

1. $f(x)=x+3$ is an injection from $[3,4]$ to $(5,7]$
2. $f(x) = \frac{x}{10} + 3$ is an injection from $(5,7]$ to $[3,4]$